# I want to move Picturebox inside drew ellipse

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I already drew ellipse using

```
g.DrawEllipse(p, 0, 0, 100, 100);
p = new Pen(Color.Red, 1f);
```

This is my code for moving picturbox

```
int x, y;
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        y+=5;
        x += 2;
        pictureBox3.Location = new Point(x, y);

        Invalidate();
      }
```

Picture box move in correctly ...
But I want ...**How can i move Picturebox inside that ellipse?**
Ellipse should be fixed one..

Comment: make sure that you don't overstep the borders of your ellipse. Or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: You can either calculate the ellipse points or use a GraphicsPath and test if all corners are still inside the path. We can't help more without knowing how you actually want to move.. For a nice reflexion you will need math, however anyway.

Comment: As i think you got my point.I wanted know if picturebox try move border of ellipse comeback again and move inside that ellipse

Comment: _comeback again_ you need to be much more precise and detailed if you want to code! step 1: define a speed vector!

Comment: I'll try it..thanks Taw